# Lots of foreign keys on one table - performance issue

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, foreign-keys

I have a large table that consists mostly of **enumerated values** (40 different enums).

Each enum value is a foreign key to a separate table because I need to allow the user to customize the name and add/remove new values.
These enum tables are very small, at most 20 values in each.

Each foreign key is indexed, so there is about **50 indexed keys** in total.
This makes **insertions** and **updates** very slow.

There is about **2 million rows** in the main table and it **keeps growing**.

What is the best practise to represent these enum values/improve performance?

Should I **remove some of these indexed keys** that are not used during searches and keep only the foreign keys or **split the main table into multiple tables** by grouping enums that share some "category"?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan (as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) of a slow insert and update statement generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers) insert ...`** - not just a "simple" explain

Answer (score 0):

You have many reference tables, and your large main table has columns pointing to each of them. This is a common way to design a group of tables.

What purpose do your fk relationships serve? They compel database consistency, and that can be useful. For example, if you had a column in your main table called `food_id`, and it pointed to a row in a six-row table called `food`, your fk relationship would prevent you from INSERTing a value that pointed to the eighth row.

But compelling that consistency requires a lot of checking of values. It makes your inserts and updates slow. You know that.

I suggest you simply drop all the foreign key relationships from main table to reference tables, and drop the indexes on those columns in the main table.  The worst that can happen? You get an occasional value in one of those columns that points to a nonexistent row in a reference table.  You can mitigate that as follows:

```
 SELECT main.item, main.item2, COALESCE (food.name, '--missing--') name
   FROM main
   LEFT JOIN food on main.food_id = food.food_id
```

The left join will yield a null value for a missing `food_id` value, and the `COALESCE()` will show a default value.

And your insert operations will become fast.